# Why animation is not displaying front while streaming in android

Tags: android, animation, frame, http-live-streaming

I am doing an radio streaming app. I am trying to display some loading bar frame by frame animation before my stream begins. but the animations starts after playing the stream only. How could i show my anim before stream loads. Here is my code snippet. Help is appreciated...

```
      bhajan_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager)         getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo Info = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (Info == null) {
                Toast.makeText(BhajanStream.this, "POOR SIGNALS ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }

            else {

                loadanim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loader_1);
                loadanim.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loadanim);
                loadanimation = (AnimationDrawable) loadanim
                        .getBackground();
                loadanimation.isVisible();
                effectanim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.effect_1);
                effectanim.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.musiceffect);
                effectanimation = (AnimationDrawable) effectanim
                        .getBackground();
                bhajan_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bhajan_start);
                bhajan_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bhajan_stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadanim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                effectanim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(rs_bhajan_uri);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }

    });

      }

protected void onPreExecute() {
    // UI work allowed here

    loadanimation.start();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `prepareAsync()` rather than just `prepare()`.
From the [MediaPlayer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29):

> For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), which returns
>   immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered.

(Calling prepare will block your Ui Thread until the data is prepared, meaning that updating your views has to wait until the preparation is done)

Example implementation:

```
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @DAVE I used prepareAsync() but no audio is playing. why?

Comment: Using prepareAsync prepares the player in another thread - it return immediately, even though it is still preparing. You should set an OnPreparedListener on the player, and start playing when its onPrepared()-method is called.

Comment: I modified my answer with an example.